# Servers the same config, but dns not work on one

Tags: networking, server, dns

I have strange situation, this might be some stupid problem with fast resolution, but I cant' figure out it.

I have 2 servers. Both are configured the same (only different IP). One work great, but second can't resolve a DNS.

First was installed as 17.04 and upgraded to 17.10. Second is fresh 17.10 Ubuntu Server with gnome.

On both servers I can ping any IP address on internal and external network.

**First Server (works fine):**

/etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1
#iface eno1 inet dhcp
iface eno1 inet manual
#iface eno1 inet static
#   address 10.1.1.200
#   netmask 255.255.255.0
#   gateway 10.1.1.253
#   network 10.1.1.0
#   broadcast 10.1.1.255
#   mtu 1500

auto eno1.1390
iface eno1.1390 inet static
    address 10.66.64.9
    netmask 255.255.252.0
    gateway 10.66.64.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 10.66.95.249 10.1.1.254
#   network 10.66.64.0
#   broadcast 10.66.66.255
#   mtu 1500
    vlan-raw-device eno1
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 10.66.95.249
nameserver 10.1.1.254
nameserver
```

**Second server (have issue)**

/etc/network/interfaces

```
# /etc/network/interfaces -- configuration file for ifup(8), ifdown(8)
# Generated by debian-installer.

# The loopback interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1
#iface eno1 inet dhcp
iface eno1 inet manual
#iface eno1 inet static
#   address 10.1.1.201
#   netmask 255.255.255.0
#   gateway 10.1.1.253
#   network 10.1.1.0
#   broadcast 10.1.1.255
#   mtu 1500

auto eno1.1390
iface eno1.1390 inet static
    address 10.66.64.10
    netmask 255.255.252.0
    gateway 10.66.64.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 10.66.95.249 10.1.1.254
#   network 10.66.64.0
#   broadcast 10.66.66.255
#   mtu 1500
    vlan-raw-device eno1
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

Comment: Is `dns-nameserver` a valid key? or does it need to be `dns-nameservers`?

Comment: Indeed. Notice it is correct `dns-nameservers` in the one that works and `dns-nameserver` in the one that doesn't.

Comment: Ok my bad, because I war trying config with one dns server. Then I had backed to main setting wrong. I fix it (now is `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 10.66.95.249 10.1.1.254` but I get the same log in `resolv.conf`